# The character of a newform

Tags: modular-forms, galois-representations

In "Modular Forms and Fermat's Last Theorem" Chp.1, p.7 Glenn Stevens talks about the character of a weight 2 newform $\epsilon$ in relation to the characteristic polynomial of a Frobenius element. However he does not define or show where the value comes from.

Also Ken Ribet in the following paper, http://modular.math.washington.edu/edu/Fall2003/252/lectures/11-12-03/11-12-03.pdf on newforms introduces $\epsilon$ on p.2 but again without any reference to its origin.

I would like to understand what the character of the newform represents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Chapter 9 of William Stein's book](http://wstein.org/books/modform/modform/newforms.html#sec-decompdirchar), in particular Definition 9.3.